# Politique sur les demandes de ressources / Policy on resource list questions

Tags: discussion, question-quality, resources, answer-quality

Notre site a accumulé un certain nombre de questions du type « sur quel site puis-je trouver … » ou « quel livre lire pour … ». La plupart de ces questions ont l'étiquette [ressources](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ressources).

La grande majorité de ces questions sont restées ouvertes ([56 ouvertes](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bressources%5d%20closed%3a0), [15 fermées](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bressources%5d%20closed%3a1) — il y en a aussi 22 supprimées), mais n'ont obtenu pour la plupart que des réponses médiocres, pour la plupart des liens vers tel ou tel site avec au mieux un commentaire anecdotique et invérifiable du type « j'ai aimé ça » (dont on ne sait pas si c'est du lard ou du spam).

C'est un problème que beaucoup de sites sur Stack Exchange ont rencontré (« *list questions* »). Le format de Stack Exchange n'est pas adapté à ce type de questions qui sont plus des sondages de popularité. Les votes sur les réponses ont tendance à avant tout favoriser les réponses les plus anciennes, ensuite les sites/livres/films/… les plus populaires, et rarement la qualité de la ressource et encore moins son adéquation à la question proposée.

Il y a bien quelques exceptions ([1](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/822/fran%C3%A7ais-dafrique/876#876), [2](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7053/learning-materials-for-french-from-novice-to-professional/7055#7055)), mais elles sont malheureusement rares. Il faudrait faire le ménage.

**Quelles sont les questions à conserver ? Quelles sont les réponses à conserver ?**

Les modérateurs peuvent fermer des questions et effacer des réponses quel que soit leur score, donc vous pouvez signaler un contenu qui vous paraît inapproprié même si vous n'avez pas les moyens de le fermer ou de l'effacer par manque de réputation. Mais nous ne le ferons qu'en l'application d'une politique claire définie sur le site méta. Cette question est une invitation à débattre d'une politique claire.

Nous en avions discuté en 2011 : [Are resources for learning French on-topic? Les demandes de ressources pour l'apprentissage du français sont-elles valables ?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127/are-resources-for-learning-french-on-topic-les-demandes-de-ressources-pour-lap) La position dominante à l'époque (la mienne) était :

> - Garder quelques demandes de ressources très générales, en wiki communautaire, et consolider toutes les réponses. On peut éventuellement avoir plusieurs réponses en wiki, mais partagées par thème (par exemple, une réponse pour des ressources sur le web et une pour des ressources papier) et non par contributeur.
> - Être très libéraux lorsqu'il s'agit de clore des questions futures comme doublons.
> - Les demandes suffisamment spécifiques qui ne peuvent pas être raisonnablement couvertes par une demande générique peuvent rester. La politique en matière de recommendations du site Literature Stack Exchange[¹](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206) peut nous inspirer, avec ici un fort accent sur le caractère spécifique de la question par rapport aux demandes générales.

Comment: Je viens juste de comprendre le jeu de mots... Pas mal ;-). Mais j'avais déjà plussoyé la question, peux pas replussoyer pour ça.

Answer (score 3):

Accepter ce genre de questions ne peut qu'éloigner FL d'un site de langue où sont débattues de véritables questions de/sur la langue. Les questions sur des demandes de ressources<sup>1</sup> sont en général très vagues et ne suscitent pas de réponses intéressantes.
Il faudrait décourager ce genre de questions en les fermant et orientant les demandeurs vers Cosette.

Par contre nous pourrions envisager d'avoir un wiki **ressources pour l'apprentissage du français langue étrangère** ici, sur meta, à l'instar de ce qui est fait sur [ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english).

---

<sup>1</sup> Je fais la différence avec la demande d'avis sur une ressource spécifique (par exemple qui demanderait à des francophones d'évaluer la qualité du français d'un site de ressources).